The Colored Jones function & Wilf-Zeilberger-Algorithmus
While I am working on my thesis based on the article ‘The coloured Jones function is q-holonomic’ by the two authors Stavros Garoufalidis and Thang TQ Lê, several questions have arisen about the mathematical argumentation in this publication. In my eyes, these questions point to gaps and ambiguities in the mathematical argumentation, which makes it difficult or even impossible to successfully complete the given task. Furthermore, the supervisor and reviewer of the thesis is not willing to answer any of my questions or provide clarity to close the gaps.
The task is to implement the Wilf-Zeilberger algorithm for calculating the Coloured Jones polynomial of a long knot K from a braid representation of K as well as the A-hat polynomials.
Not only was so far nobody able or willing to answer my questions in regard to the task. Also, my research has shown that there is no implementation of the Wilf-Zeilberger algorithm that can solve the problem based on the above-mentioned article.

uh... what is your question?
